# Simplify previous element selection before parent

Tags: jquery

I'd like to simplify the selection of the `.layer` element in this tree:

```
<dt class="item">
    <span class="layer"></span>
    <span class="data"><span class="box"></span></span>
</dt>
```

my current position `$(this)` is the `.box` element, from there I'd like to select the `.layer` element.

In my current solution I go back to the parent and select the child element     `.parents('.item').find('.layer')` but I'd rather avoid the path through the parent. I tried to do it with `.prev('.layer')` but it does not seem to work and I don't know what elese could work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery has parent and prev selectors:

```
$(this).parent().prev();
```

Comment: Why did I not think of connecting the two methods? Great, it works like desired now.

Comment: @t3chb0t - why go with the more brittle method that can't tolerate any changes to the HTML?  Generally you want the most robust code that is the least likely to break if other things are changed.

Comment: @jsfriend00: in my case this is the more reliable solution because I have another list where a similar `dt` has a different class name from `.item` and I did not want to go too far back I also do not want to use element names in my selectors because it is even more sensitive to later changes

Answer (score 1):

The safest way to do this that won't break if slight changes are made to the HTML would be:

```
$(this).closest(".item").find(".layer")
```

The issue with `.prev()` is that is requires an element to be in an exact position or it will not work.  When you tried `$(this).prev()`, there is no previous sibling from .box so it couldn't find anything.

The more brittle way to target it (that relies on exact positioning of all elements) would be:

```
$(this).parent().prev()
```

I would not recommend that because minor formatting changes to the HTML could easily break that (suppose someone decides to add one more `<span>` in the wrong place) whereas my first recommendation is tolerant of pretty significant HTML changes without breaking.  Unless you're doing hundreds to thousands of these in a loop, it is unlikely you'd see a noticeable performance difference.

Comment: my final solution is a mix of both answers `$(this).parent(".data").prev(".layer")` this way I can add more elements in future and I don't have to use the `dt.item`

Comment: @t3chb0t - I don't think `.prev(".layer")` does what you think it does.  It looks at the one and only one `.prev()` item and only returns it if it matches ".layer".  It does not go find the .layer item in the previous direction regardless of how far away it is.  This is a common misconception.